# Prevent Emacs paredit it in clojure (or cider) mode from inserting a space after a single quote when opening brackets

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider, paredit

I'm not sure what caused the change, but now my emacs paredit will insert a space after a single quote when opening a new closure. I do not have this issue in elisp. I have not changed my clojure config in months and have nothing custom beyond toggling existing variables.

What I have -> what I want

`' ()` -> `'()`

`' []` -> `'[]`

`' {}` -> `'{}`

Comment: With no idea what your emacs configuration is, hard to say anything but "works on my machine".

Comment: seems like a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135315/prevent-paredit-from-inserting-a-space-when-inserting-parentheses-and-other-is?rq=1 one of the answers shows how to do that